OnetoOne Mapping if column names are different in both table JPA
There are 2 Oracle table
Parent (parent_id, name, desc)
Child (id, child_id references Parent(parent_id), created_dt)

child_id is foreign key referencing parent_id in Parent table.
Since the two tables have different name for primary foreign column, the OnetoOne Mapping is created as below :
Parent.java

    String name;
    String desc;
    String parent_id;
    
    @OneToOne(cascade= {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referenceColumnName="child_id", nullable= true, insertable=false, uptadable= false)
    private Child child;
    
    //getters & setters


Child.java
    String id;
    String child_id;
    Timestamp createdDt;

 
    //getters & setters

When I try to save using JPA into Parent(ParentRepositary.save) and groovy test cases, I am getting below error:
Referential integrity constraint violation : PARENT FOREIGN KEY(PARENT_ID) REFERENCES CHILD(CHILD_ID).
But in database child_id(foreign key) is referencing to parent_id(primary key). The same ParentRepositary.save is working fine with junit.
Is there anything specific to Mapping relationship that is declared wrong that groovy test case is failing.
Test:
Parent p = new Parent();
p.setParent_id("P123");
p.setName("name");
p.setDesc("desc");
parentRepositary.save(p);

parentRepositary is extending JpaRepositary.

Please don't downvote without fully reading & understanding the issue. Its not that simple error, I wanted to understand why groovy is taking reverse relationship.


Is there anything specific to Mapping relationship that is declared wrong

Yes.
Most directly, a @JoinColumn annotation declares a foreign key column in the table of the entity in which the annotation appears.  As you can see, that's exactly what the diagnostic you present describes, but not how you say the database is structured.
More generally, since the foreign key appears in the child's table, the relationship is part of the persistent state of the child, not of the parent.  That is, the child needs to be the owning side of this relationship.  Since you apparently want it to be navigable from the parent side (too), you'll want to set it up as bidirectional.
Something like this, maybe:
@Entity
public class Parent {

    @Id
    private String parent_id;

    private String name;

    private String desc;

    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = true,
            mappedBy = "parent")
    private Child child;
    
    // ...
}

@Entity
public class Child {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "child_id", nullable = true, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Parent parent;

    private Timestamp createdDt;
    
    // ...

    // Possibly:
    public String getChild_id() {
        return (parent == null) ? null : parent.getParent_id();
    }
}

Note that you can have different cascade and fetch type settings on the two sides of that relationship.

Note also that it presents practical problems for the join column to not be insertable or updatable.  It must be at least one of those if you want to be able to create new Child entities that have Parents.  So it's agood thing that the join column is nullable.  It follows that, although the cascade type does not declaratively prevent it, you will not be able to successfully cascade PERSIST operations from Parent to Child.
If, for the sake of argument, you wanted every Child entity to have a Parent, but not necessarily that every Parent have a Child, then you would want to map the relationship rather differently: optional only on the parent side, with the join column insertable and non-nullable.
Also, are you sure that you are defining the database structure correctly?  It would make so much more sense for a foreign key named child_id to belong to the parent, referencing the child, than for it to be the other way around as you describe.  That would also make your initial mapping attempt closer to right.
Additionally, be aware that when you persist a relationship between new entities, the non-owning side needs to be persisted first, so that it is assigned an ID for the owning side to reference.  This may be the actual nature of the error you describe, the mapping issues notwithstanding.

Issue is resolved, the mistake I made was @Id was marked to another column in Parent which was defined unique. But I really appreciate for answer you provided as it elaborated what one can do wrong in setting up mapping. Your explanation is helpful in understanding mapping & how it works.
